# neo4j authentication extension not finding user

Tags: java, plugins, neo4j

So I have an instance of neo4j 2.0 M3.
I wanted to use the authentication found here

```
 https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/authentication-extension
```

I added the jars to the plugins folder and added to my server config

```
#security settings
org.neo4j.server.credentials=admin:mypassword
org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.server.extension.auth=/auth
```

But when I went to do a GET request

```
curl --user admin:mypassword http://localhost:7474/auth/list
```

I was met with

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /auth/list. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
```

Is this due to the server being on 2.0 and the authentication plugin being on 1.9?  Thanks!

Comment: I think so, I can look into upgrading the plugin for 2.0 but you'll have to build it on your own I think.

Comment: Ya thats fine.  How extensive are the changes it needs to make between versions?  If its not too complicated I'd be interested in forking